# How to get one login page for multiple systems?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have four systems running on the same server. I want to let the users to log in once for all the systems. I made one user-management system to create users and edit them.

I tried to save in the session but it didn't help.

Any suggestions? I am working on asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

Most resolve around the login happening at a central site, which then returns with an identity information field (login token) that the target site uses to retreive the user.

When you go to another site, the site redirects you shortly to the central site and if you are logged in (persistent cookie) you get back the identity of you.

Alternatively you can do a lot with referrers and playing around.

YOu want to do some research on the internet - what you loo kfo is "Single Sign On".

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms

has some technical discussions.

Across complete separate websites (domains) you can read up on

http://aspalliance.com/1513_Cross_Site_Authentication_and_Data_Transfer

howw to do it - obviously shared cookies will not work there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with Federated Security.  If you were using Windows Authentication then you could use Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS).  In this model, users reference a Web application and the principal on the current thread is checked.  If the value is null then information stored in the web.config will redirect the request to a login page automatically.  This is assuming there is no a Windows security context, otherwise the user can be automatically logged in.

After the user is successfully logged into the environment, the principal on the thread is populated and a set of claims are issued that are specific for that user.  Since the claims are associated with the principal and not with a specific application, they can be used across the board by any claims aware application.

If you aren't using Windows Authentication, you can still accomplish the same thing, the only problem is that you cannot use ADFS.  Instead, you'll have to implement your own Identity Provider to replace ADFS.  The .NET Framework does provide base classes and interfaces to help you accomplish that.

Comment: Unless the poster uses AD - which is 95% likely he is not, because this ONLY is feasible in an intranet scenario and there you can use integrated security (and before you ask, yes, you can use AD on the internet - happy paying, a CAL per user) this simply is a technology that is not applicable. As most websites are internet facing, and Federated Security does not work in the scenario of managing public users... -1.

Comment: Tom you are absolutely wrong.  You can use Windows based authentication on the Web.  How do you think Outlook Web Access works.  You have no idea what you're talking about.  Not only do I suggest that Windows Authentication could work, but then I go on to say that implementing a custom identiy provider would also provide federated security.  Nice work on being an idiot.

Comment: @ChristopherW.Szabo Ah, the words if ingnorants. Yes, you CAN use WIndows authentication on the internet. Sadly that means one CAL for every user. THat is feasible for OWA and any other intranet scenario, it is not feasbile in the standard scenarios where "users" are internet users. Any clue how much for exampl StackOverflow would have to pay for Windows licenses for people like you would they decide to run user manageement in windows? There is a reason no website uses it - it is useful when you control the user population and they have windows licenses, stupid when you put up a website.

Comment: Where exactly in the original post was it specified that this was public facing and not internal?  You made an assumption without full requirements.  I provided a solution that would deal with an internal set of applications or a public facing set.  In once case, ADFS could be used as the identity provider, in another a custom implementation would be necessary.  The fact of the matter is that the solution, in general, is federated security.  Something upon which you have yet to comment.  Instead of looking to tear down suggetions, maybe you should try privding constructive feedback.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest looking into ActiveDirectory or any LDAP server for single signon to access all applications.  If you cannot (or do not wish to) use LDAP, you could implement similar functionality (but with more development work/time spent) with any memory/disk store.   If this is not possible, please share why as it might be useful to others.

Hope this helps.